# Почему classList.add() не работает в функции?

Tags: javascript

При запуске консоли пишет:

> Cannot read property 'classList' of undefined.

Почему?

```js
var slideIndex = 1;
var slides = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-item');
var prev = document.querySelector('.prev');
var next = document.querySelector('.next');
var dots = document.querySelector('dot');
var dotsWrap = document.getElementsByClassName('slider-dots');
showSlider(slideIndex);

function showSlider(n)  {
    if (n > slides.length) {
        slideIndex = 1;
    }
    if (n < 1) {
        slideIndex = slides.length;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = 'none';
    }

    for (var u = 0; i < dots.length; u++) {
        dots[u].classList.remove('dot-active');
    }

    slides[slideIndex - 1].style.display = 'block';
 dots[slideIndex - 1].classList.add('dot-active');

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Массив `dots` короче, чем массив `slides`.

---

Пардон. `dots` вообще не массив, а один элемент или `null`.